Does this ersatz of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma hold?
Let us consider $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R^2})$. I'd like to know if one can apply some sort of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to this quantity :
$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}, \, I(k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,k)e^{-ikx}dx$
Since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R^2})$, using Fubini's theorem we deduce that $k \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x,k)|dx < + \infty$ almost everywhere i.e. $x \mapsto f(x,k) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for almost every $k \in \mathbb{R}$ so $I(k)$ is well-defined for almost every $k$.
Could we prove that $\underset{k\to+\infty}{\text{lim}} I(k) = 0$ ? Adapting the proof from https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma, at fixed $k \in \mathbb{R}$ we could decompose $x \mapsto f(x,k)$ into a sum of step functions but with coefficients depending on $k$. To conclude, we would need  that these coefficients vanish at infinity but I don't know if that's true.

There is a  counter-example of the following type: $f(x,k)=g(k)e^{-x^{2}/2}$, $g(k)=c_n$ on $(n, n+s_n), n=1,2,...$. You can take $c_n=e^{(n+s_n)^{2}/2}$ and choose $s_n$ small enough to make $g$ integrable.

I wouldn't have come up with this idea alone, thanks
